# How would I pull a subset of data from 1 table and put it in a 2nd table?

Tags: java, sql, groovy

I am not too familiar with Groovy but I need to get a subset (about 5000 rows) of data from a large table and insert it into another already existing table. The contents of the second should be deleted and by the end of the process should only contain the subset of data from table 1. The tables are on a AS-400 database. Im not sure if that makes a difference at all. Thanks in advance for any help.

The following is what I have so far but its probably not even close to right.It asks for a target and source column, the connectionId for the database being used and what table is the defined set table.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<custom-script-transformer name="Subset Data Load" table="false">
   <description>Refresh target table columns with source table columns</description>
   <category>SWBC</category>
   <fieldvar name="Target_Column">
      <description>Column to be updated</description>
   </fieldvar>
   <fieldvar name="Source_Column">
      <description>source column</description>
   </fieldvar>
   <paramvar name="dsConnId" dataType="string">
      <description>Defined set connection id</description>
      <default-value>default</default-value>
   </paramvar>
   <paramvar name="dsTable" dataType="string">
      <description>Defined set table</description>
   </paramvar>
   <script>
      import groovy.sql.Sql;

      if ( dsConnId == 'default' ) {
         sql = new Sql(datasource);
      } else {
         sql = new Sql(connectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(dsConnId).getDataSource());
      }
      q = sql.getDataSource().getConnection().getMetaData().getIdentifierQuoteString();

      def rows = sql.rows("select #Source_Column from #dsTable")
      assert rows.size() == 5000

      #Target_Column = #Source_Column;
      sql.close();
   </script>
</custom-script-transformer>
```

Comment: i don't know, what tool this is, but it _looks_ like your code works with columns there (or you have some var name abuse going on) and the question is about whole rows.  doesn't this boils down to `delete from target; insert into target select * from source` within an transaction?

Comment: It is a datamasking tool. Kind of buggy though. We are working with specific fields and and all the rows there within about to row 5000. Unfortunately the DB is really old and doesnt have an "id" field. We are trying to do it in the most time efficient way. If there is a better way to do it please enlighten me. I really don't have a good grasp on this stuff at all. As far the sql syntax, Im not sure if there is a specific way that groovy wants to see it to interpret it. And would it be better to use a sql.execute("command")?